# Twilio - Sending attachments during a video call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We have a use case when we want to make a photo of participant A and send it to participant B. If we render the canvas image on the side B of the A's camera, the quality is not optimal for us, even with the highest quality video. What we want to do is to render a canvas image of A's camera (confirmed, quality is much better) on the A's side and send it over to B. Data track api sounds like what we need, but as far as I understood it's limited to 16KB only.

Any ideas/approaches how to make a photo/snapshot of camera A and transfer it to B using Twilio API?

P.S. Of course, we could do it ourselves using e.g. websockets, but we wanted to avoid extra complexity.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are correct that the recommended maximum size of the payload sent over the data track is 16KB, but you can send many of these payloads and build the response up on the other side.

You can check out some examples of splitting files and sending via WebRTC here:

- [How to Send a File Using WebRTC Data API](https://bloggeek.me/send-file-webrtc-data-api/)
- [Real time communication with WebRTC](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0)